# Ubuntu & Virtualbox cannot see USB Devices

Tags: ubuntu, usb, virtualbox

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with VirtualBox 6.1.22, I can see USB Devices in the Ubuntu file manager, but I cannot see the device in the Windows 10 Virtual OS.

I have tried the USB Device settings for the VM to no avail.

How do I fix this?

Comment: I think you have to install the extension pack, you can find it here [https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/](https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/).

Comment: The Virtualbox extensions are already loaded.

Comment: Then next if I remember correctly you have to add your user to the vbox group, the close and reopen the session. [Look here](https://askubuntu.com/a/377781/931617).

Comment: Thank you, I found that as well.  Still does not work.

Comment: When you go to the vm configuration → USB, are the controllers enabled?

Comment: Yes, one at a time they are enabled.

Comment: Does it happen with other vms? Maybe you can try with a linux one.

Comment: This is the only VM I have at the present time.  I would like to run Quickbooks on the VM, but I cannot transfer data to the VM to get started.

Comment: The other option is to use shared folders.

Comment: OK, I need to add Shared folders then, because I cannot see the USB Device on the Startup Settings configuration screen.  None of this makes any sense.  Is there a logfile that I can review?

Comment: As simple as this seems to be, I am also blocked from making this happen.  The Configuration appears straight forward, I have selected the USB Drive for sharing, and also used the unused Drive Letter for Mounting purposes.  Still nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to install extension pack and enable USB3 support the guest. Even is the device is plain old USB1/2 it will not work within guest machine as long as no USB3 support is enabled.

This is a bug in Virtual Box I believe and made me a few grey hairs until I realized.

Answer (score 1):

All of the information in the above article accurately depicts the steps necessary to establishing the USB Sharing on the VM.

The one thing that wasn't mentioned was that the Host OS needs to be updated in order for updates to the Group membership is recognized.

Thank you schrodigerscatcuriosity for your assistance.